# Websites using scrapy-playwright and only playwright work differently

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, playwright, playwright-python

I am trying to log into a webpage using scrapy-playwright, as I want the nice integration with scrapy. I can't log in using scrapy-playwright, as it redirects to a page that does not exist. I have also tried doing a post request instead of clicking, that doesn't work either.

However, if I try the same thing using only Playwright, it works perfectly... Is there a difference between websites opened with scrapy-playwright compared to only Playwright? And does anyone know how to solve this using scrapy-playwright?

scrapy-playwright code:

```py
def start_requests(self):
    yield scrapy.Request(
        url = self.url,
        meta = dict(
            playwright = True,
            playwright_include_page = True,
            playwright_page_methods = [PageMethod('wait_for_selector', 'a[data-toggle=dropdown]')],
                ),
        callback = self.sign_in,
        )

async def sign_in(self, response):
    page = response.meta['playwright_page']
    while await page.is_visible("button[class='close close-news']"):
        await page.click("button[class='close close-news']")
    await page.click('button#declineAllConsentSummary')
    await page.click('div.my-account-sub > a[data-toggle=dropdown]', timeout=10000)
    await page.fill('input#j_username_header', os.getenv(self.usernameKey), timeout=10000)
    await page.fill('input#j_password_header', os.getenv(self.passwordKey), timeout=10000)
    await page.click('button#responsiveMyAccLoginGA')
```

Playwright code:

```py
async def test_async_playwright(self):
    async with async_playwright() as playwright:
        browser = await playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False)
        context = await browser.new_context(base_url=self.url)
        page = await context.new_page()
        
        await page.goto(self.url, wait_until='commit')
        while await page.is_visible("button[class='close close-news']"):
            await page.click("button[class='close close-news']")
        await page.click('button#declineAllConsentSummary')
        await page.wait_for_selector('a[data-toggle=dropdown]')
        await page.click('div.my-account-sub > a[data-toggle=dropdown]', timeout=5000)
        await page.fill('input#j_username_header', os.getenv(self.usernameKey), timeout=5000)
        await page.fill('input#j_password_header', os.getenv(self.passwordKey), timeout=5000)
        await page.click('button#responsiveMyAccLoginGA')
```

Comment: What is the error you get when you use the "bad" code?

Answer (score 3):

I used to have the same problem as you. Here's how I solved it.

- Step 1: Of course you must have an account of that website
- Step 2: If you don't know the playwright code, you can try the playwright [codegen](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/codegen) feature to fake your login to the website action.

  - Note that you need to save Browser [storage state](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/auth).
  - Copy all steps generated from Playwright Inspector Window.
- Step 3: Using storage state file in scrapy-playwright code

More detailed. imagine that i am trying to login my favorite site named babypips. The code below helps me login and save Browser storage state. Maybe it's because my internet is a bit slow, so i add one more another address navigation step. This is **login.py**

```
from playwright.sync_api import Playwright, sync_playwright
from configparser import ConfigParser
from pathlib import Path
current_folder = Path(__file__).parent.resolve()

def run(playwright: Playwright) -> None:
    # Loading user info
    config = ConfigParser()
    config.read(f"{current_folder}/accounts.ini")
    user = input("What is your name?: ")
    try:
        config_data = config[user]
    except:
        print("User not found!")
        exit(0)

    browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False)
    context = browser.new_context()

    # Open new page
    page = context.new_page()

    # Go to https://www.babypips.com/account/sign-in
    page.goto("https://www.babypips.com/account/sign-in")

    page.wait_for_timeout(500)
    # Click [placeholder="Email or Username"]
    page.click("[placeholder=\"Email or Username\"]")

    page.wait_for_timeout(500)
    # Fill [placeholder="Email or Username"]
    page.fill("[placeholder=\"Email or Username\"]", config_data['username'])

    page.wait_for_timeout(500)
    # Click [placeholder="Password"]
    page.click("[placeholder=\"Password\"]")

    page.wait_for_timeout(500)
    # Fill [placeholder="Password"]
    page.fill("[placeholder=\"Password\"]", config_data['password'])

    page.wait_for_timeout(500)
    # with page.expect_navigation(url="https://www.babypips.com/"):
    with page.expect_navigation():
        page.click("button:has-text(\"Sign In\")")

    page.wait_for_timeout(500)
    page.get_by_role("navigation").get_by_role("link", name="MarketMilk™").click()
    page.wait_for_timeout(1000)
    
    # Save storage state into the file.
    context.storage_state(path="babystate.json")

    # ---------------------
    context.close()
    browser.close()


with sync_playwright() as playwright:
    run(playwright)
```

Define your state file in **settings.py** like below

```
REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION = '2.7'
TWISTED_REACTOR = 'twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor'
FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING = 'utf-8'
COOKIES_FILE = 'babystate.json'
HTTPERROR_ALLOWED_CODES = [403]

DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS = {
    "http": "scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler",
    "https": "scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler",
}
```

After that using **state file** when call scrapy **start_requests** in your **crawler**. You put the file so that it can be found by scrapy

```
from crawldata.settings import COOKIES_FILE

    ......

    def start_requests(self):
        ....
        yield Request('https://marketmilk.babypips.com', meta={
            'playwright': True,
            'playwright_include_page': True,
            'playwright_context': 'new',
            'playwright_context_kwargs': {
                'storage_state': COOKIES_FILE,
            },
            'playwright_page_methods': [
                *tz_methods,
                PageMethod('keyboard.down', 'End'),
                PageMethod('wait_for_timeout', 500),
            ],
            'errback': self.errback,
        },)
        ....

    async def errback(self, failure):
        page = failure.request.meta["playwright_page"]
        await page.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

As a possible workaround, if you are redirected(to the broken page) after the token/cookie is granted, you can as well navigate to a normal site url, and you should be logged in